# how write percentage symbol in math mode jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, data-science

When I write % in between $$ $$ it looks like this. please help me in this

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display a percent character using SymPy and LaTeX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41085492/how-to-display-a-percent-character-using-sympy-and-latex)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to escape special characters in latex you can use backslash (\). So, in your case you could use `\%`